# You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_example_tensor' with dtype string and shape [1]

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am developing a tensorflow serving client/server application by using [chatbot-retrieval](https://github.com/dennybritz/chatbot-retrieval/) project.

My code has two parts, namely serving part and client part.

Below is the code snippet for the serving parts.

```
def get_features(context, utterance):

  context_len = 50
  utterance_len = 50

  features = {
    "context": context,
    "context_len": tf.constant(context_len, shape=[1,1], dtype=tf.int64),
    "utterance": utterance,
    "utterance_len": tf.constant(utterance_len, shape=[1,1], dtype=tf.int64),
  }

  return features


def my_input_fn(estimator, input_example_tensor ):
      feature_configs = {
              'context':tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[50], dtype=tf.int64),
              'utterance':tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[50], dtype=tf.int64)
              }
      tf_example = tf.parse_example(input_example_tensor, feature_configs)
      context = tf.identity(tf_example['context'], name='context')
      utterance = tf.identity(tf_example['utterance'], name='utterance')
      features = get_features(context, utterance)
      return features

def my_signature_fn(input_example_tensor, features, predictions):
  feature_configs = {
          'context':tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[50], dtype=tf.int64),
          'utterance':tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[50], dtype=tf.int64)
          }

  tf_example = tf.parse_example(input_example_tensor, feature_configs)
  tf_context = tf.identity(tf_example['context'], name='tf_context_utterance')
  tf_utterance = tf.identity(tf_example['utterance'], name='tf_utterance')

  default_graph_signature = exporter.regression_signature(
              input_tensor=input_example_tensor,
              output_tensor=tf.identity(predictions)
              )

  named_graph_signatures = {
              'inputs':exporter.generic_signature(
                  {
                      'context':tf_context,
                      'utterance':tf_utterance
                  }
               ),
              'outputs':exporter.generic_signature(
                  {
                      'scores':predictions
                  }
               )
              }

  return default_graph_signature, named_graph_signatures

def main():
      ##preliminary codes here##

      estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn_train, steps=100, monitors=[eval_monitor])

      estimator.export(
              export_dir = FLAGS.export_dir,
              input_fn = my_input_fn,
              use_deprecated_input_fn = True,
              signature_fn = my_signature_fn,
              exports_to_keep = 1
              )
```

Below is the code snippet for the client part.

```
def tokenizer_fn(iterator):
   return (x.split(" ") for x in iterator)

    vp = tf.contrib.learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor.restore(FLAGS.vocab_processor_file)

input_context = "biz banka kart farkli bir banka atmsinde para"
input_utterance = "farkli banka kart biz banka atmsinde para"

context_feature = np.array(list(vp.transform([input_context])))
utterance_feature = np.array(list(vp.transform([input_utterance])))

context_tensor = tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(context_feature, shape=[1, context_feature.size])
utterance_tensor = tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(context_feature, shape=[1, context_feature.size])

request.inputs['context'].CopyFrom(context_tensor)
request.inputs['utterance'].CopyFrom(utterance_tensor)

result_counter.throttle()
result_future = stub.Predict.future(request, 5.0)  # 5 seconds
result_future.add_done_callback(
_create_rpc_callback(label[0], result_counter))
   return result_counter.get_error_rate()
```

Both of the serving and client parts builds with no error.  After running the serving application and then the client application I get the following strange error propogated to the client application when the rpc call completes.

Below is the error I get when rpc call completes

```
AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details="You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_example_tensor' with dtype string and shape [1]
         [[Node: input_example_tensor = Placeholder[_output_shapes=[[1]], dtype=DT_STRING, shape=[1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]")
```

The error is strange since there seems to be no way to feed the placeholder from the client application.

How can I provide data for the placeholder 'input_example_tensor' if I am accessing the model through tensorflow serving?

**ANSWER:**
(I posted my answer here since I couldn't post it as an answer due to lack of StackOverflow badges. Anyone who is volunteer to submit it as his/her answer to the question is more than welcome. I will approve it as the answer.)

I could resolve the problem by using the option use_deprecated_input_fn = False in estimator.export function and change the input signatures accordingly.

Below is the final code which is running with no problem.

```
def get_features(input_example_tensor, context, utterance):
  context_len = 50
  utterance_len = 50
  features = {
    "my_input_example_tensor": input_example_tensor,
    "context": context,
    "context_len": tf.constant(context_len, shape=[1,1], dtype=tf.int64),
    "utterance": utterance,
    "utterance_len": tf.constant(utterance_len, shape=[1,1], dtype=tf.int64),
  }

  return features

def my_input_fn():
  input_example_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name='tf_example_placeholder')

  feature_configs = {
          'context':tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[50], dtype=tf.int64),
          'utterance':tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[50], dtype=tf.int64)
          }
  tf_example = tf.parse_example(input_example_tensor, feature_configs)
  context = tf.identity(tf_example['context'], name='context')
  utterance = tf.identity(tf_example['utterance'], name='utterance')
  features = get_features(input_example_tensor, context, utterance)

  return features, None

def my_signature_fn(input_example_tensor, features, predictions):   
  default_graph_signature = exporter.regression_signature(
              input_tensor=input_example_tensor,
              output_tensor=predictions
              )

  named_graph_signatures = {
              'inputs':exporter.generic_signature(
                  {
                      'context':features['context'],
                      'utterance':features['utterance']
                  }
               ),
              'outputs':exporter.generic_signature(
                  {
                      'scores':predictions
                  }
               )
              }

  return default_graph_signature, named_graph_signatures

def main():
  ##preliminary codes here##

  estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn_train, steps=100, monitors=[eval_monitor])

  estimator._targets_info = tf.contrib.learn.estimators.tensor_signature.TensorSignature(tf.constant(0, shape=[1,1]))

  estimator.export(
          export_dir = FLAGS.export_dir,
          input_fn = my_input_fn,
          input_feature_key ="my_input_example_tensor",
          use_deprecated_input_fn = False,
          signature_fn = my_signature_fn,
          exports_to_keep = 1
          )
```

Comment: Are you able to get the stack trace of the error? It is not clear what are the type and shape of the value actually provided, which leads to the error.

Comment: I could resolve the problem by using the option use_deprecated_input_fn = False in estimator.export function and change the input signatures accordingly. StackOverflow doesn't accept answer from my account since I am new to the site and have this question downvoted.

Comment: can you please upvote the question so that I can post the running code for the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP self-solved but couldn't self-answer, so here's their answer:

Problem was fixed by using the option `use_deprecated_input_fn = False` in `estimator.export` function and changing the input signatures accordingly:

```
def my_signature_fn(input_example_tensor, features, predictions):   
  default_graph_signature = exporter.regression_signature(
      input_tensor=input_example_tensor,
      output_tensor=predictions
      )

  named_graph_signatures = {
      'inputs':exporter.generic_signature(
          {
          'context':features['context'],
          'utterance':features['utterance']
          }
       ),
      'outputs':exporter.generic_signature(
          {
          'scores':predictions
          }
       )
      }

  return default_graph_signature, named_graph_signatures

def main():
  ##preliminary codes here##

  estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn_train, steps=100, monitors=[eval_monitor])

  estimator._targets_info = tf.contrib.learn.estimators.tensor_signature.TensorSignature(tf.constant(0, shape=[1,1]))

  estimator.export(
      export_dir = FLAGS.export_dir,
      input_fn = my_input_fn,
      input_feature_key ="my_input_example_tensor",
      use_deprecated_input_fn = False,
      signature_fn = my_signature_fn,
      exports_to_keep = 1
      )
```